# TransientObjectException when loading an object from database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an error that makes me go nuts. When I try to create a new object, Hibernate returns an error :

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: EquipmentType; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before

I have the following Spring services :

CommandService

```
public class CommandService implements ICommandService {
    @Override
    public Command createCommand(String name, String eqpName) {
        Command cmd = new Command();        
        Equipment eqp = getEquipment(eqpName);

        cmd.setEquipment(eqp);      
        cmd.setName(name);

        return cmd;
    }

    @Override
    public Equipment getEquipment(String eqpName) {
        IEquipmentService eqpService = (IEquipmentService) SPRING_CONTEXT.getBean("EquipmentService");

        Equipment eqp = eqpService.findEquipmentByName(eqpName);

        EquipmentType eqpType = new EquipmentType();
        eqpType.setName("MyType");
        eqp.setType(eqpType);

        Model model = new Model();
        model.setName("MyModel");
        eqp.setModel(model);

        eqpService.saveEquipment(eqp);

        return eqp;     
    }
}
```

EquipmentService

```
public class EquipmentService implements IEquipmentService {

    private DAO dao; // This DAO is autowired

    @Override
    public void saveEquipment(Equipment eqp) {
        completeModel(eqp);
        completeEqpType(eqp);

        ((EquipmentDAO) dao).merge(eqp);
    }

    private void completeModel(Equipment eqp) {
        IModelService modelService = (IModelService) SPRING_CONTEXT.getBean("ModelService");
        Model result = modelService.findModelByName(eqp.getModel().getName());  // Fails here

        eqp.setModel(result);
    }

    private void completeEqpType(Equipment eqp) {
        IEquipmentTypeService eqpTypeService = (IEquipmentTypeService) SPRING_CONTEXT.getBean("EquipmentTypeService");
        EquipmentType result = eqpTypeService.findEquipmentTypeByName(eqp.getType().getName());

        eqp.setType(result);
    }
}
```

Note that all the methods of `IEquipmentService` and `ICommandService` are configured as transactional.
My object `Equipment` is composed of a `Model` and an `EquipmentType`.
Those objects refer already created objects in database, that is why I don't want to save them again.

Here is the Hibernate configuration :

```
<class name="Equipment" table="equipment" lazy="false">
        <id name="equipmentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="EQUIPMENT_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="type" class="EquipmentType" fetch="join" not-null="true">
            <column name="TYPE_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="model" class="Model" fetch="join" not-null="true">
            <column name="MODEL_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
</class>
```

**EDIT** : As requested, here are the methods `equals(..)` and `hashcode(..)`

For Equipment

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((equipmentId == null) ? 0 : equipmentId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((model == null) ? 0 : model.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if (obj instanceof Equipment) {
        Equipment eqp = (Equipment) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(this.equipmentId, eqp.getEquipmentId()).isEquals();
    }

    return false;
}
```

For Model and EquipmentType, those methods are not explicitly defined.

Can you help me to figure out why this error is returned when I call `createCommand(..)` ?

Comment: How have you defined equals() and hashcode() method for your model classes? Can you add those in question details.

Comment: @mohit I edited my original post. Note that `EqualsBuilder` is provided by Apache Commons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set new `EquipmentType` and `Model` in your `getEquipment` method. As you haven't defined equals() and hashcode method in these 2 classes, hibernate is unable to compare these with already persisted objects. It sees them as detached (because equals() and hashcode() methods are indicating new objects instead of existing objects). That's why it ask you to save equipment type and model objects first.

I think you should override equals() & hashcode() properly in EquipmentType & Model.

---

EDIT

I think you shouldn't add new EquipmentType as you override it again in completeType() method. Why don't you change your API to

```
EquipmentService#saveEquipment(Equipment e, Sting type, String modelName){
    EquipmentType t = findType();
    Model m = findModel();
    e.setType(t);
    e.setModel(m);
}
```

If you can't change APIs, you will have to persist new type and model first before hibernate flush is triggered.

Comment: But my `equals()` methods would compare the IDs of those objects. In `getEquipment()`, my objects don't have any ID, so they would still be considered as detached, would they ?

Comment: New objects remain detached as you are not saving them before flush is triggered. Flush is automatically triggered whenever select query is executed. I have edited the answer to give a work-around.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why does hibernate has to flush if the transaction is not ended yet ?

Comment: Hibernate doesn't always flush at transaction commit. If hibernate has to run a select, it must first sync all in memory changes with databases so that in memory objects can also appear in search result.

Comment: So you are telling me there is no way to create a Java object and then perform a select on the database without persisting that object ? Isn't that weird ?

Comment: Before performing a select, you must insert a row in database. Hibernate is just a layer over DB. So, before selecting objects, they must be saved first.

Comment: But here the object `EquipmentType` has no direct link with the `Model` object... This makes me perplex... (not regarding your answer but regarding the way Hibernate handles stuff)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96371/discussion-between-mohit-and-dounyy).